# Pairing new device in Lock Task Mode (Android P/10)

Tags: java, android

I have an issue when I use the Lock Task Mode (Kiosk mode) on Android.

In "normal" mode, when I try to pair a device, a pop-up message appears :
"Are you sure you want to pair the Bluetooth Device?" Yes/No

But in Lock Task Mode, the message doesn't appear.

I added in my code to authorize notifications but pop-up are not displayed :

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
            int test = dmp.getLockTaskFeatures(adminComponentName);
            dmp.setLockTaskFeatures(adminComponentName, DevicePolicyManager.LOCK_TASK_FEATURE_SYSTEM_INFO |
                                                                                DevicePolicyManager.LOCK_TASK_FEATURE_NOTIFICATIONS |
                                                                                DevicePolicyManager.LOCK_TASK_FEATURE_HOME);
        }
```

Is there a way in Lock Task Mode to authorize such pop-ups?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Bluetooth extends AppCompatActivity {
    ArrayList<String> listItems=new ArrayList<String>();
    //DEFINING A STRING ADAPTER WHICH WILL HANDLE THE DATA OF THE LISTVIEW
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    BroadcastReceiver mReceiver;
    DevicePolicyManager dpm;
    ComponentName deviceAdmin;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_bluetooth);

         dpm = (DevicePolicyManager) Bluetooth.this.getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
         deviceAdmin = new ComponentName(Bluetooth.this, MyDeviceAdminReceiver.class);
        dpm.setLockTaskPackages(deviceAdmin, new String[]{
                Bluetooth.this.getPackageName()
                "com.android.settings"
        });
        ListView lista=findViewById(R.id.devices);
        adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listItems);
        lista.setAdapter(adapter);

        BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

        //setdevicevisible();
        boolean hasBluetooth = getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH);
        if(!hasBluetooth) {
            AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Bluetooth.this).create();
            dialog.setTitle("Bluetooth nem elérhető");
            dialog.setMessage("Bluetooth ki van kapcsolva!");
            dialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            // Closes the dialog and terminates the activity.
                            dialog.dismiss();
                            Bluetooth.this.finish();
                        }
                    });
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
            dialog.show();
        }

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                    1);
        }

        
        if (mBluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()) {
            mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        }

        mBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
        mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                String action = intent.getAction();

                //Finding devices
                if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action))
                {
                    // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
                    BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                    // Add the name and address to an array adapter to show in a ListView
                    //device.setPairingConfirmation(true);





                    if (device.getName() != null) {
                        adapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
                        device.createBond();

                    }

                    //adapter.add(device.getAddress());
                }
            }
        };

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        try{
            unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
            dpm.setLockTaskPackages(deviceAdmin, new String[]{
                    Bluetooth.this.getPackageName()
            });
        }catch (Exception e){
            // already unregistered
        }
    }
}
```